# Remembering the search patterns in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

Am trying to understand the "remembering the search patterns in shell script". Could not able to understand the differences between the mentioned below.

**`$ echo abcd123 | sed 's:\([a-z]*\)\([0-9]\):\2 \1:'`**

1 abcd23

**`$ echo abcd123 | sed 's:\([a-z]*\)\([0-9]\).*:\2 \1:'`**

1 abcd

**`$ echo abcd123 | sed 's:\([a-z]*\).*\([0-9]\).*:\2 \1:'`**

3 abcd

Answer (score 1):

When you have an exercise like this, break each regex down to its components. E.g. the first one

- `'s:find:replace:'` is the basic substitution form.
- The *find* being `\(...\)` a capture group of `[a-z]*` (zero or more lower-case characters) followed by
- `\(...\)` a second capture group of `[0-9]` (exactly one digit).
- Your *replace* is a *backreferene*  `\2` (the contents of the second capture group) followed by
- a space and finally
- the content of the first capture group `\1`.

If you approach each of the regex in this manner it will make it easy for you to identify and remember the differences.